# How to split a string in Liquidity?

Tags: smart-contracts, liquidity

I'm attempting to split apart a string by "." so that "my.name" returns {"my", "name"}. However, I can't seem to find an in-built method of performing this operation in Liquidity.

Lately, I've tried implementing my own split function by using `String.slice`, which produces a substring from given indexes. This poses another problem because I have to search through the string for the indexes of ".", which doesn't seem easy either.

Long story short, my current train of thought is to break the string into a list of characters (which I haven't been able to implement), iterate through to find the indexes of ".", and then use `String.slice` to obtain my list of split phrases.

Is there an easier, straightforward way of splitting strings in Liquidity? If not, how can I implement the above process or alternative solution in Liquidity?

Comment: Why? There is no easy way to do this because it is not expected to be useful.